# display number of files in current moment like what tail -f do

Tags: linux, shell, ls, tail

I have a folder which files are copied to it like `/home/my/`. I want to run a command which shows number of files inside it in real time like what `tail -f` do with file contents. I know I should run `ls *|wc -l` to count files but I don't know how to do it for monitoring and keep it running.

Comment: @txtechhelp please post it as answer

Answer (score 1):

If you have the [`watch`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watch_%28Unix%29) command available on your distribution, you can run it like this:

```
watch -n 1 "ls /home/my"
```

This will run the `ls /home/my` command every `n` seconds (`1` in this example) and will display the output to the screen.

Hope that can help.

Answer (score 0):

Without `watch` you can try:

```
while sleep 1 ; do ls /home/my ; done
```